# Keep v-menu open state when the activator is pressed again

Tags: vuejs2, vuetify.js

I'm trying to make a custom v-autocomplete using v-text-field and v-menu.
What confuses me is that v-menu closes when you click on the v-text-field again. The first click on the v-text field opens the v-menu, and the second click closes it. I couldn't find any property that turns off toggle mode.

Although, if you look at the html markup, v-menu is used in the v-select and v-autocomplete components, which close when you click on the content or outside the menu.

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/Mikentosh/pen/oNoNEmq)

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <v-app id="inspire">
      <div class="text-center">
        <v-main>
          <v-container>
            <v-row>
              <v-col cols="3">
                <v-menu bottom offset-y max-height="304px">
                  <template v-slot:activator="{ on, attrs }">
                    <v-text-field v-model="model && model.title"
                    dense color="primary"
                    v-bind="attrs" v-on="on"
                    label="Choose" outlined>
                    </v-text-field>
                  </template>
                  <v-list dense>
                    <v-list-item-group v-model="model"
                    color="primary">
                      <v-list-item v-for="(item, index) in items"
                      :key="item.id" :value="item"
                      dense>
                        <v-list-item-title>{{ item.title }}</v-list-item-title>
                      </v-list-item>
                    </v-list-item-group>
                  </v-list>
                </v-menu>
              </v-col>
            </v-row>
          </v-container>
        </v-main>
      </div>
    </v-app>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  data: () => ({
    items: [
      {id:1, title: 'Click Me 1' },
      {id:2, title: 'Click Me 2' },
      {id:3, title: 'Click Me 3' },
      {id:4, title: 'Click Me 4' },
    ],
    model: null
  }),
})
</script>
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.